# How to read database from project folder

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hello and good morning! 
I have created a folder named db and imported a database file into that folder in my project in eclipse. When I try to stablish the connection I get an error saying unknown database “users” I understand the URL is set to localhost so the driver doesn’t see the database. Fix I’m looking for is
1. Where in the computer is localhost located so I can put my database file there?
2. How can I read and write to the database located at my project location or any other location than localhost?

I’m using JDBC and the MySQL server is running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What format is this "database file" you have? `.sql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MySQL database runs as a process somewhere (the local computer or remote server). The file or folder you have may be the data itself, but it's just sitting there, doing nothing. You'll need to load it in MySQL to use it, a process known as "import".

If you happen to have a file with "data", you need to somehow **IMPORT** it into the database server. If you are using MySQL server, then:

- Is it installed in your local computer?
- Is it running?
- Do you have a username/password to connect to it?
- Did you create a new schema/database to store your data?

If you are good with the above, then you can start importing the data into your database, tables, indexes, etc.

Once the import is finished then you can start querying the data as you wish, by connecting to the MySQL server using JDBC or any other technology you want.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I used SQLite3 to fill the database with data so now I need to migrate from SQLite3 to MySQL. Or is there a way to use SQLite3 syntax from java using JDBC?

Comment: As far as I know, you can use SQLite3 from Java using a JDBC driver. You don't need to import it into MySQL. For example: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/